# $f \in C^{\infty} \Longleftrightarrow (g \circ f) \in C^{\infty} \; \forall \, g \in C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be two embedded manifolds and let $f : M \longrightarrow N$. Show that $f$ is smooth if and only if the composition $(g \circ f)$ is smooth for every smooth map $g : V \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $V \subseteq N$ is open.

$\bullet \;$ The direction $f \in C^{\infty} \Longrightarrow (g \circ f) \in C^{\infty}$ is easy, using the proposition that the composition of smooth maps is smooth again.

$\bullet \;$ The direction $(g \circ f) \in C^{\infty} \Longrightarrow f \in C^{\infty}$ however gives me some troubles. I have the feeling that the proof is actually quite easy - yet I am unable to conclude it. If I could assume that there always exists some diffeomorphism $\varphi$ between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}$, then I could simply set $g = \varphi$ and I would be done, wouldn't I? Unfortunately, this assumption is rather bold, I suppose, and so I am stuck at this point.

${}$

The definition for smoothness granted is the following one:

**Definition:** A map $f : M \longrightarrow N$ between manifolds is called *smooth* if for all $p \in M$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U_p \in \mathbb{R}^m$ of $p$ and some smooth map $F : U_p \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F \, |_{U_p \cap M} = f \, |_{U_p \cap M}$.

Comment: There never exists a diffeomorphism $V \cong \mathbb{R}$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: Sorry, not $n > 1$, but $\dim{N} > 1$.

Comment: Have you tried using local coordinates?

Comment: Cannot we just take $g=\operatorname{Id}$ for the reverse direction ?

Comment: @zwim There exists no identity map between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Nevermind, I overlooked the fact $g$ was $\mathbb R-$valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for any locally defined smooth map $g:N\to \mathbb R$, $g\circ f$ is smooth. And let us show that $f$ is $C^1$ at some point $p \in M$.

Let $U,V$ be open subsets of $M,N$ respectively, such that $p \in U$, $f(U)\subset V$ and let $ \phi= (x^\mu)_{\mu = 1}^{\dim N}$ be a set of local coordinates on $V$.

Then, each $x^\mu \circ f$ is $C^\infty$. Therefore, $\phi\circ f: U\to \mathbb R^n$ is $C^\infty$. $\phi $ being a (local) diffeomorphism, we conclude that $f$ is $C^\infty$ on a neighborhood of $p$, and therefore on $M$.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! This is the kind of elegantly simple but yet effortlessly convincing approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As $N$ is a manifold, there exists a smooth chart $(V, \varphi)$ such that $\varphi : V \to \mathbb{R}^{\dim{N}}$ is a diffeomorphism. Consider the components of $\varphi \circ f|_{f^{-1}(V)}$ and continue from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. Although both you and SolubleFish sketched the same approach, I accepted SolubleFish's answer because it was more elaborate. I hope you don't mind.